# Capture stderr in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

How to capture stderr from a step in GitHub Actions? For example:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: fails with error
    id: fails
    run: |
      command_that_fails
  - run: |
      echo ${{ steps.fails.outputs.stderr }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? The output gets shown in the GitHub UI.

Comment: I'm planning to automatically open an issue with the `stderr` as content

Comment: Have you read https://github.community/t/stdout-stderr-not-available-if-action-fails/116229/4

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to pipe stderr to a file, then `cat` that into a step output variable.

I ran into issues with capturing the output with `set-output` directly, specifically the variable would be empty.

```
- name: try something that might fail
  id: maybe_fails
  run: |
    # run command and capture stderr
    command_that_fails 2> errors.txt || true
    echo ::set-output name=errors::`cat errors.txt`
    # run again to get exit code
    command_that_fails
- name: use error detail on failure
  if: ${{ failure() }}
  run: |
    echo ${{ steps.maybe_fails.outputs.errors }}
```

Comment: Any way to do this without running the command again?

Comment: @juan Some variation of `exit_code=0; command_that_fails 2> errors.txt || exit_code=$? && true` then `[ $exit_code -ne 0 ] && set output && exit $exit_code`  might work. Or maybe `command_that_fails 2> errors.txt || echo -e "\n$?" >> errors.txt && true` then `[ -f errors.txt ] && exit_code="$( tail -n 1 )" && [ $exit_code -ne 0 ] && set output && exit $exit_code`. I haven't tried either approach.

Comment: @juan Just do `status=$?` after the initial call to `command_that_fails`. Then, at the end of the step, add `exit $status`.